# JS - How to promisify and add listeners to events?

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm implementing a solution using newman and I really want to avoid callback functions because I need some sync steps and it's a pain follow callbacks. To convert the function to promise, I'm using lib `util` as follows:

```
const newman = require('newman');
const util = require('util')

run() {
    const newmanPromise = util.promisify(newman.run)

    return newmanPromise({
        collection: "...",
        environment: "...",
        insecure: true
    })
}
```

It works like a charm but now I need add a listener to specific event. In regular newman implemantation it should be:

```
run() {

    newman.run({
        collection: '...',
        environment: '...',
        insecure: true
    }, this.callback).on('console', function (err, args) { 
        console.log(args.messages.join(' '));
    })

}

callback(error, summary) {
    console.log('Error:', error);
    console.log('Summary:', summary);
}
```

Is there any viable way to convert to promises and add listeners?

Comment: You could look into using [rxjs](https://rxjs.dev/), which handles streams better than promises. Looks like they have a `fromEvent`, although it seems geared toward DOM events.

Comment: Please don't add secondary questions to already-answered questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promises are great when you are waiting for *a thing* to happen.

The problem is that console events are not *a thing*, they are lots of things.

`on("console",...)` fires *every time* the script runs a console function.

When dealing with something that happens multiple times, you still need to use callback functions.

Comment: And how can I handle when I need to have a listener and wait for a thing to happen? Use callbacks?

Comment: Yes, use callbacks, that is what I said.